# How to train word2vec model to work better on producing synonym of adjective words?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, nlp, word2vec

I need to train word2vec model to produce synonyms of any user input adjetive words using **unsupervised learning** from some corpus, and ideally, the produced synonyms are also adjective words.

I have removed all punctuations, space, treated all numbers and proper noun as the same term respectively, and done lemmatization when pre-processing the corpus.

I use Skip Gram model(not sure if this is the best soluion for this problem) and generate training batch using *generate_batch()* function taken from TensorFlow, which generates (center_word, context_word) pairs:

```
def generate_batch(batch_size, num_skips, skip_window):
  global data_index
  assert batch_size % num_skips == 0
  assert num_skips <= 2 * skip_window
  batch = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size), dtype=np.int32)
  labels = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, 1), dtype=np.int32)
  span = 2 * skip_window + 1  # [ skip_window target skip_window ]
  buffer = collections.deque(maxlen=span)
  if data_index + span > len(data):
    data_index = 0
  buffer.extend(data[data_index:data_index + span])
  data_index += span
  for i in range(batch_size // num_skips):
    target = skip_window  # target label at the center of the buffer
    targets_to_avoid = [skip_window]
    for j in range(num_skips):
      while target in targets_to_avoid:
        target = random.randint(0, span - 1)
      targets_to_avoid.append(target)
      batch[i * num_skips + j] = buffer[skip_window]
      labels[i * num_skips + j, 0] = buffer[target]
    if data_index == len(data):
      buffer[:] = data[:span]
      data_index = span
    else:
      buffer.append(data[data_index])
      data_index += 1
  # Backtrack a little bit to avoid skipping words in the end of a batch
  data_index = (data_index + len(data) - span) % len(data)
  return batch, labels
```

Basically, the code for training the model is also almost the same as TensorFlow tutorial sample code. I have run it few times with different batch-size, skip-windwo-size, learning rate etc, but the result is far from being acceptable, most produced synonyms are not even adjective. So my questions are:

1. If I only generate training batch when the center word is adjective, and simply slide the window when it is not, is this approach considered as **unsupervised**?
2. Is there anything that needs to be redesigned in *generate_batch()* function? I was told that it is better to redesign this function to work better for this specific case, but I have no idea what can be improved except question 1 approach.
3. How to produce adjective synonyms? I used to think that a skip-window of size 4-7 would tend to capture semantic meanings(if I did not understand what I have learned wrong), and distinguish adjective from other type of words, but this is not what I am getting.
4. Regarding the parameters: skip-window-size, batch-size, learning-rate, is there any commonly used values to experiment?

Any advice on how to improve would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our linguistic concept of a 'synonym' is narrower than the similarity reflected in the word-positions found by word2vec-like algorithms.

In particular, what we consider 'antonyms` generally appear as very similar in word-vectors, because the words *are* very similar in most aspects and the contexts in which they appear – only contrasting in some specific, topic-related way.

As a result, most-similar (nearest-neighbor) word lists tend to include synonyms, but also other related words.

Possible directions for better results would include:

- labeling words with part-of-speech info before training, and then filtering neighbor-lists to only include adjectives
- testing different context-window sizes - often small windows emphasize functional similarities ("can this word be used in the same places?") and larger windows topical similarities ("are these words used in the same discussions?")

(Unverified thought: the best adjectival synonyms might appear near the top of most-similar lists based on small-context-windows, *and* large-context-windows.)

Comment: what I have done: 1. label all adj using spacy(by comparing token.pos and token.dep, but it seems not accurate?), 2. remove all punctuactions, stopwords, symbols, space and numbers, exclude the most and least frequent words from my volcabulary and replace them with 'NA', lemmatization, then a sentence like 'This flower related book costed Jack $5.' will become ['NA', 'relate', 'book', 'cost']. 3.replace all words by their frequency rank(a int). 4.generate training batch only when center word is labelled adj, and chose non-'NA' context word as training label. Any problem?

Comment: Are you removing stopwords and most/least-frequent words because it helped? Because it's not strictly necessary (beyond the `min_count` enforceable in word2vec) and might hurt. Nor is lemmatization strictly necessary. (It might help with smaller corpuses, but the original word2vec work didn't do it, and it might make reconstructing synonym-sets harder.) Nor is changing lots of words to `'NA'` likely to help - better to drop words, than coalesce them into a nonsense word interfering with neighbor words. Also not sure why words would be replaced by frequency-rank – that's also atypical for w2v.

Comment: Finally, unsure why you'd want to limit training to just /ADJ words, unless you'd tried it both ways and found that to help. Word2vec learns from bulk, varied contexts – and lots of your steps serve to thin out the contexts, which might hurt just as much as it might help. (Words and variants that seem like junk to you might help flesh-out the positions of other words of interest.) If you can verify your extra steps help, sure, do them – but don't improvise extra steps that you can't quantitatively verify are helping.